# Move UIView based on which text field has been tapped

Tags: uiview, uikeyboard

I have two text fields on one of my views and I am trying to figure out how to move the view to different positions based on which text field has been tapped.

The function to move the view works absolutely fine on 4 inch devices as there is enough space for both textfields to fit between the top of the view controller and the keyboard. However on 3.5 inch devices there is only enough room for one text field to be shown at a time.

Here is the code I currently have:

viewWillAppear:

```
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillShow:", name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWillHide:", name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

keyboardWillShow/keyboardWillHide:

```
    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var screenSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height

    if screenSize == 480 {
        //
    } else {
        if keyboardActive == false {
            if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.CGRectValue() {
                //let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardSize.height, right: 0)
                var frame = self.budgetEntryView.frame
                frame.origin.y = frame.origin.y - 87 //keyboardSize.height + 167
                self.budgetEntryView.frame = frame
                keyboardActive = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I figure out which text field has been tapped and move the view based on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the isFirstResponder method for each textView to find out which one has been tapped.